# Why is my /dist folder unaccessible in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

So I want to access `/dist/main.js` (which is a webpack file with my style and css)into my layout.

The main page is `welcome.jsp` and I access it through:

```
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name="WelcomePage",  urlPatterns="/index")
public class WelcomePage extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

The URL in my layout is : `<script src="/dist/main.js"></script>`

And I've never have specified in my `web.xml` anything about servlet-mapping or something like this.

I guess this is a problem of redirection since when I access the url I'm ending up on my home page.

Where am I doing wrong ?

This is my folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try making it `<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/dist/main.js"></script>`

Could you access it via web by pointing your browser to absolute path?